# Write 2D array of image data in file in Android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, bufferedimage

I have a 2D array of image data in which I did some manipulations, but image is not getting saved on path specified i.e. `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+File.separator+"output.png"`.

I did the same code for Desktop application it is working fine in core Java. I have used `BufferedImage` to save `2D array` of image data in a file. It is working totally fine, but I was wondering why this is not working in `android`. I did some research on this also, I got to know that `Bitmap` is the alternative for `BufferedImage` but the image is not getting written. Here I am posting my code please help me.

This is my java code:

```
BufferedImage theImage = new BufferedImage(imageWidth, imageHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        for (int y = 0; y < imageHeight; ++y) {
            for (int x = 0; x < imageWidth; ++x) {
                theImage.setRGB(x, y, imgData[x][y]);
            }
        }
        File outputfile = new File(filename);
        try {
            ImageIO.write(theImage, "png", outputfile);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
```

Android code that I've tried:

```
int i =0;
        for (int y = 0; y < imageHeight; ++y) {
                for (int x = 0; x < imageWidth; ++x) {
                    values[i] = (byte) imgData[x][y];
                i++;
            }
        }
    try {
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(values, 0, values.length);
                    OutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(filename);           
                    fos.write(values);
                    fos.close();
                    fos.flush();
                    res = true;
    }catch (java.io.IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to Compress Before Writing Stream ??

insert this before stream write :

```
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
```

Or: you can Use this Method:

```
private void createDirectoryAndSaveFile(Bitmap imageToSave, String fileName) {

File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DirName");

if (!direct.exists()) {
    File wallpaperDirectory = new File("/sdcard/DirName/");
    wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
  }

    File file = new File(new File("/sdcard/DirName/"), fileName);
    if (file.exists())
        file.delete();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        imageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```